# Submitting AJAX form for a nested child with another nested child (AssociationTypeMismatch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

### My models

I'm trying to create a form for an *Annotation*. This annotation belongs to a *Map*, and each annotation should have one *Boundary*. A map can have many annotations.

[image]

I first created the association by letting both *Annotation* and *Map* `has_one` *Boundary*, but later I switched to using a polymorphic `boundary_object`. The error was the same regardless.

```
has_one :boundary, :as => :boundary_object         # <= Map
has_one :boundary, :as => :boundary_object         # <= Annotation
belongs_to :boundary_object, :polymorphic => true  # <= Boundary
```

---

### Views and Controller

Here's the thing: First I used `Boundary.new` to create a new boundary object here, since I didn't have a pre-set annotation object, since the form can be submitted multiple times.

#### `maps/show.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for([@map, Annotation.new], :remote => true ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, :cols => 80, :rows => 10, :style => "width: 500px" %>
    <%= f.fields_for Boundary.new do |b| %>
      <%= b.text_field :ne_x, :style => "display:none" %>
      <%= b.text_field :ne_y, :style => "display:none" %>
      <%= b.text_field :sw_x, :style => "display:none" %>
      <%= b.text_field :sw_y, :style => "display:none" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I could use `f.fields_for :boundary` too, if I have this in the `maps_controller.rb`:

```
@annotation = @map.annotations.build
@annotation.boundary = Boundary.new
```

But the result is still the same.

#### `annotations_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @annotation = Annotation.new(params[:annotation])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @annotation.save
      format.js { }
  end
end
```

---

### The Error

When submitting that form, this results in the following error at the first line in the `create` method.

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Boundary(#2158793660) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#2165684420))

Obviously, the form works without the whole boundary thing. These are the parameters submitted:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"6GDF6aDc6GMR3CMP+QzWKZW9IV9gSxfdkxipfg39q7U=",
  "annotation"=>
  {
    "body"=>"foo bar",
    "boundary"=>
    {
      "ne_x"=>"11312", 
      "ne_y"=>"5919", 
      "sw_x"=>"6176", 
      "sw_y"=>"1871"
    }
  }, 
 "map_id"=>"1"
}
```

What do I have to do to be able to create the *Boundary* object for this annotation right away?

Comment: Have you tried using `f.fields_for :boundary` instead of `f.fields_for Boundary.new`? (Note that you must have association called `boundary` inside your Association model)

Comment: This doesn't produce any output. How do I get "association called boundary inside your Association model"? I thought using `has_one :boundary` in the `annotation.rb` and `map.rb` would suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your associations:

**First**, you need to build a new boundary object (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more info):

```
def show
  @map = ...
  @annotation = @map.annotations.build
  @boundary = @annotation.build_boundary # build new boundary
end
```

**Second**, you need to edit your view:

```
<%= form_for([@map, @annotation], :remote => true ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :cols => 80, :rows => 10, :style => "width: 500px" %>
  <%= f.fields_for :boundary do |b| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Third**, check that you have **accepts_nested_attributes_for** for your Boundary in the Annotation model.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :boundary
```

The form will then look like this – note that the name of the association needs `_attributes`:

```
<input … name="annotation[boundary_attributes][ne_x]" … />
```

Comment: `boundaries` table has an annotation_id column ? Or it is a polymorphic association ?

Comment: No, both map and annotation have a `boundary_id` column each. It's not a polymorphic association. Is that wrong? Should I use a polymorphic `belongs_to` instead?

Comment: It depends. If boundary connects Map and Association, then - no ([nice guide to associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)). I believe there is an error in the picture above. I can't see association between map and annotations.

Comment: "It doesn't connect them in any way" - than you need to use polymorthic association both for Map and Annotation model.

Comment: I now used a polymorphic association (see question update) but the error is still the same. The form looks the same, the parameters sent look the same, so the error message stays.

Comment: Could you check that accepts_nested_attributes_for is present is your Annotation model (see updated answer)

Comment: Okay, I added all that, also made the `attr_accessible :boundary_attributes`, and when in the controller I reach `Annotation.new(params[:annotation])`, I get: `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: body, boundary):` — if I then also allow assigning `body` and `boundary`, I get the same `AssociationTypeMismatch` as from the beginning.

Comment: Okay, whatever happened here, I managed to fix it – without needing the `attr_accessible`. It works almost as you wrote. Updated your answer with my working code. Thanks for taking so much time to help me!